# Passing 2d array to function in Lua

Tags: function, lua

It is possible to pass 2d array to a function as a paramter ?
I initialized an array like this :

```
tab={}
for i=1, 10 do
    tab[i]={}
    for z=1, 10 do
        tab[i][z]= 0
    end
end
```

and i have function like this :

```
function foo(data)
    ...
    x = data[i][z] -- here i got error
    ...
end
```

The gave the error message `attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)`

All variables are declared and initialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work if it is initialized *properly*.

For example, the below code sample will output 3:

```
function foo(data)
  local i, z = 1, 2
  print(data[i][z])
end

local tab={}
for i=1, 10 do
  tab[i]={}
  for z=1, 10 do
    tab[i][z]= i + z
  end
end

foo(tab)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can share the rest of your code? The following runs with no error:

```
tab={}
for i=1, 10 do
    tab[i]={}
    for z=1, 10 do
        tab[i][z]= 0
    end
end

function foo(data)
    print(data[3][2])
end

foo(tab)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The gave the error message attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

I got such errors while changing metatable of some variable.